# I cant map array of objects eventhough it's printed in console.log

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mongoose, redux

I'm trying to map an array of objects but it keeps saying that docs are undefined even though I can clearly see it in console.log

This is what I get when I ***console.log***

```
{console.log(this.props.results.data)}
```

[image]

what I want is in the **docs** field. If I expand it looks like this

[image]

Since I want to print out the content of docs this is what I tried doing

```
<div className='list-render'>
   {this.props.results.loading ? <LoadingSpinner/> : 
      <div className='row'>
         {(this.props.results.data.docs.map((data) => { // code to print individual fields )}
      </div>
   </div>}
</div>
```

I get **TypeError: this.props.results.data.docs is undefined** I'm using mongoose-paginate-v2 library for pagination

Comment: Try `{(this.props.results.data && this.props.results.data.docs.map((data) => { // code to print individual fields )}`

Comment: still says the same thing

Comment: Then the results are not available (yet). Change your `console.log()` to `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.results))` and check the output. A better alternative would be to add a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: as @Andreas already mentioned i too have faced this issue before..the value you see in the console may not be present at current time also if you update any value in the array it will be reflected in the previous logs too due to reference i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the `docs` property is not undefined. You can do that in a couple of ways:

1. You can use optional chaining to check if the property is not `null` or `undefined`. Then your code will look like this `this.props.results.data?.docs.map...`. [Here's how you add it to your react app](https://dev.to/aumayeung/how-to-use-the-optional-chaining-operator-in-your-react-app-right-now-1ocj) (but if you are using the latest babel version - it should work out of the box)
2. You do the check yourself. The most basic one is, as suggested in the comment, is to check if the property is falsy:

```
this.props.results.data.docs && this.props.results.data.docs.map((data)
```

The comment is a bit incorrect though, you don't need to check if `data` is falsy (only if the error is pointing at that), you check if `docs` is falsy.

Comment: You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for that: `this.props.results.data?.docs.map`