# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" when using useState and useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm new to using useState and useEffect and I'm trying to fetch users from randomuser api and display them. I'm following the documentation and I can see my users array logged into the console.

What can I change so it doesn't tell me "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".

Would appreciate the help.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Layout, Loading } from "../components";
// import config from '../config.json';

const Overview = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [devices, setDevices] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function callApi() {
      const response = await axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10");
      const devices = response?.data?.results;
      setDevices(devices);
      // const response = await axios.get(`${config.serverAPI}/devices`);
      // const devices = response?.data?.status === 'success' && response?.data?.devices;
      console.log("Devices", devices);

      await localStorage.setItem("devices", JSON.stringify(devices));
      setLoading(false);
    }
    callApi();
  }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="overview-page-wrapper">
        {loading && <Loading />}
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div>{devices[0].name.first}</div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Overview;
```

```
import ReactGA from "react-ga";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import Disclaimer from "./Disclaimer";
import Header from "./Header";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";

const Layout = ({ children, match }) => {
  ReactGA.pageview(match.url);
  console.log(111, match.url);

  return (
    <div className="page-wrapper">
      <Sidebar />
      <div className="main-section">
        <Header />
        <div className="content"> {children} </div>{" "}
      </div>{" "}
      <Disclaimer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Layout);
```

Comment: make sure devices array is not empty. You can add conditional rendering in your view e.g.
{ devices.length !== 0 &&  <div>{devices[0].name.first}</div>}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I cant map array of objects eventhough it's printed in console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62508331/i-cant-map-array-of-objects-eventhough-its-printed-in-console-log)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your

```
return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="overview-page-wrapper">
        {loading && <Loading />}
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div>{devices[0].name.first}</div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
```

Because first the render method is called, and then your useEffect hook & till that time `devices` is an empty array.

and `devices[0]` is `undefined`

and when  you do `devices[0].name` you are essentially doing `undefined.name`

TO overcome this you should do something like

```
return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="overview-page-wrapper">
        {loading && <Loading />}
        <h2>Title</h2>
        {devices.length > 0 && (<div>{devices[0].name.first}</div>)}
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are preparing the loading state but it is not covering the entire render, so when you access the property it is not yet there.

To correct it you can try this:

```
<div className="overview-page-wrapper">
  {loading ? 
    <div>loading...</div> 
  : 
    <>
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <div>{devices[0].name.first}</div>
    </>
  }
</div>
```